# NGINX server location precedence

Tags: nginx, location, server, operator-precedence

I'm very new to NGINX server and I was wondering how to fix this location precedence because it doesn't work.

- I want the server to look for /phpmyadmin/ if match then use its root else use the second location block.

  ```
  location ^/phpmyadmin/.*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|3gp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|flv|mp3|mid|js|css|html|htm|wml)$ {
  root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
  }

  location ~* .(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|3gp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|flv|mp3|mid|js|css|html|htm|wml)$ {
  root /home/safeftp/www/public_html;
  expires 30d;
  }
  ```

Thank you very much in advance for your answers.
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `~*` (case-insensitive matching) syntax on the first location block. Also, it's best to get into the habit of wraping your regex in double or single-quotes just in case you have spaces, or other special characters.

```
location ~* "^/phpmyadmin/.*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|3gp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|flv|mp3|mid|js|css|html|htm|wml)$" {
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}

location ~* "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|3gp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|flv|mp3|mid|js|css|html|htm|wml)$" {
    root /home/safeftp/www/public_html;
    expires 30d;
}
```